# Rails routing with path option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please look at the below example:

```
 devise_for :users, path: ':school_id/', controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
  }

  devise_scope :user do
    get "sign_out" => 'users/sessions#destroy', as: :sign_out
    post "add_lectures" => 'users#add_lectures', as: :user_add_lectures
  end
```

When I make an ajax request to `/add_lectures` Rails thinks I am trying to access `/:school_id/users/..` because of the `path` option for users routes. In other words, Rails thinks `add_lectures` is a form of a `school_id` parameter.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

if that is in your routes file, you don't need to add it under the devise_scope. Try adding out the scope, so generic route in the routes.rb for example

`post "add_lectures" => 'users#add_lectures', as: :user_add_lectures` entry in the routes file